# GAE: Unable to update app: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Unable to deploy to GAE (java) today. I was able to deploy until yesterday evening. Anyone else has the same problem? how did you solve?

09-Mar-2016 11:15:04
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found

09-Mar-2016 11:15:04
Unable to update app: Bad authentication response: 404 Not Found

thanks

Comment: I had opened multiple google accounts. So, I did close all and deployed it again. It did deploy. It was my mistake.

Comment: Hi I am getting this exact error today and it is a little frustrating! Did you have to clear any cache or logout?

Comment: logout? yes and then login to only one google account that has your gae account.

Comment: Fyi, for me it had nothing to do with being logged in to multiple Google accounts at once. Problem was that I was using AppEngine Java SDK 1.9.2 (which uses deprecated ClientLogin). **I updated to 1.9.38 and deployment worked again.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had opened multiple google accounts. So, I did close all and deployed it again. It did deploy. It was my mistake.

Comment: Where did you open them?

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue. As it turns out the authentication method (ClientLogin) I was using to deploy to appengine was deprecated (I was deploying using **mvn gae:deploy**). Google now wants us to use their new OAuth 2.0 authentication for deploying to appengine: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/clientlogin

To fix this issue I had to update my appengine maven plugin to use the latest version so I could deploy.

I added this to my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
   <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.34</version>
</plugin>
```

Then I used this command to deploy (instead of **mvn gae:deploy**):

```
mvn appengine:update
```

For more info you can check out this info on how to deploy to appengine: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading

Comment: Thank you, that means https://github.com/maven-gae-plugin/maven-gae-plugin is now truly dead

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Google Plugin for Eclipse.
2. Open your project in eclipse. Once you install the plugin successed, you will see a new button of "G" on eclipse buttons bar.
3. Click the "G" button and then click "Deploy to App Engine".
4. Done.