# Jenkins won't deploy GAE Maven project using OAuth 2.0

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, jenkins, oauth-2.0

Lately Google got rid of deprecated `ClientLogin` authentication durning application deployment.

I followed @ttimmons answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897186/gae-unable-to-update-app-bad-authentication-response-404-not-found) and it worked fine in Eclipse run configuration deployment.

Now I want to build the application on production env using Jenkins. I've changed the **mvn gae:deploy** command to **mvn appengine:update** in Jenkins project build configuration, too. When I'm trying to run the build, application is built with no problem but when it comes to deployment I got the following Jenkins' console output:

```
Please enter code: Encountered a problem: No line found
Please see the logs *here goes system path* for further information.
ERROR: Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

In the log I have this exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.PromptReceiver.waitForCode(PromptReceiver.java:25)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.OAuth2Native.authorize(OAuth2Native.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.authorizeOauth2(AppCfg.java:486)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:130)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven32Launcher.main(Maven32Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.launch(Maven32Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this error?

Comment: Yup, forgot to post the explanation. I'll post one soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Turned out, that Jenkins had some maven authorization issue (`<servers>` node with username and password from maven's settings.xml file wasn't available). Uploading application from Jenkins machine level (cmd) solved the issue.